# Are main app and home widget live in the same memory space

Tags: android

Currently, in my main app, I have several `Threads`, which may perform read/write operation on a flat file. To avoid data corruption due to simultaneous write, I have a public static `CountDownLatch` to avoid multiple `Threads` from modifying the same file.

So far, this works pretty well.

Until recently, I'm developing a home widget feature for the main app. In home widget (or multiple home widgets), there can be multiple threads accessing the same file too.

I was wondering, is my main app & widgets inside the same memory space? Will main app & widgets see a public static `CountDownLatch` as **ONE** instance, or **TWO** instance.

So far, my initial testing is, main app & widgets are all inside the same memory space. They see a public static `CountDownLatch` as **ONE** instance. But, I just want to ensure, is there any edge cases where main app & widgets can see it as **TWO** instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering, is my main app & widgets inside the same memory space?

By default, yes, as there is only one process. However, bear in mind that your process may be terminated between when your activity is around and some time later when an app widget needs to be updated.

> But, I just want to ensure, is there any edge cases where main app & widgets can see it as TWO instance?

That would only be possible if they were running in separate processes. And, in that case, they are totally separate threads as well. Nonetheless, separate processes should not happen accidentally.

Comment: In short, can I just conclude that it is something not possible for a public static data appears as 2 instances to widget and main app?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: On a per-process basis, yes. I cannot completely rule out some odd corner cases, where one process is scheduled to be terminated and another process for your app is being created at the same time. I would hope that wouldn't happen, but I do not know enough of the Android internals to say it's impossible. Then, your public static data would have two instances, one per process.

Comment: Thanks. To avoid from shooting myself, I decide to revise my flat file implementation, and turn it into SQLite + ContentProvider solution.